# How to determine the expected chi^2 value?

Tags: chi-squared-test

My advisor is able to determine that a chi^2 value will be near 30 in this particular circumstance. I calculated a chi^2 for a dataset and fitted line to be 31.89 which validates his claim. How is he able to do this? The only features of my data that I can think of that may give someone an expected value

1. The data set has 29 degrees of freedom; is this why it is near 30? (In a chi^2 table with various levels of significance the values usually run higher than 30, about mid 30s - 40s for 29 degrees of freedom)
2. The noise distribution for each data point is normally distributed
3. If neither #1 & #2 what information do I need to provide about the dataset?

I am looking for an intuitive explanation.

**Edit/More context:** I fit a line through some data in matlab. The data is generated by the function y = (1/2)x +- noise (i.e. plus or minus some noise value). The noise values are randomly sampled from a normal distribution with mean/mu = 0 and a standard deviation/sigma = 6.

The chi^2 value is obtained by calculating the sum of the differences, ( y_i - y(x_i) )^ 2 and dividing by sigma^2. y(x_i) is the fitted line... You can think of this as SSE divided by sigma squared.

Comment: We’ll need a lot more detail about what you’re doing that gives a $\chi^2$ value.

Comment: @Dave Apologies! Just added more context.

Comment: How does $\chi^2$ arise from this?

Comment: The sum of the differences, ( y_i - y(x_i) )^ 2 divided by sigma^2 @Dave

Comment: $\chi^2(29)$ is the distribution of the sum of squares of $29$ independent standard Normal variables.  Your advisor recognized that the statistic you are using will behave approximately like such a sum of squares (because it's the sum of squares of standardized values).  At that point, they would have recalled that the expected square of a standard Normal variable must coincide with its variance (which by definition is $1$) and that variances of sums of independent variables add, whence they would immediately have concluded the expectation of your statistic should be near $29.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fragmentary answers based on what you have told us about
your data and analysis.

If $X \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = k),$ then $E(X) = k$ and $Var(X) = 2k.$
[See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) or your text or class notes for some details of chi-squared distributions.]

**P-value.** If you're doing a chi-squared test for which the null distribution is (approximately) $\mathsf{Chisq}(29),$ and the observed value of the
test statistic is $X = 31.89,$ then you can use software to find that
$P(X \ge 31.89)= 0.3247,$ which would not lead you to reject the null hypothesis.

This is the P-value of the chi-squared test. (You would reject at the 5% level if the P-value is below $0.05=5\%.)$ [Computation using R statistical software in which `pchisq` is the CDF of a chi-squared distribution.]

```
1 - pchisq(31.89, 29)
[1] 0.3247224
```

**Critical value.** Using printed tables of chi-squared distributions, you could find the
critical value $c = 42.557$ of the chi-squared test, for which $P(X \ge c) = 0.05.$

If the chi-squared test
statistic is greater than or equal to $c,$ you will reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level. The critical value can also be found using R, where `qchisq` is the inverse CDF (or 'quantile function') of a chi-squared distribution:

```
qchisq(.95, 29)
[1] 42.55697
```

**Graph.** Below is a plot of the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(29).$ The
solid vertical line shows the observed value $X = 31.89.$ The P-value is the area under the density curve to the right of this line. The dotted vertical line shows the the critical value $c = 42.557;$ the area under the density
curve to the right of this line is the significance level $5\%.$

```
curve(dchisq(x, 29), 0, 55, col="blue", lwd=2, ylab="PDF", 
   main="Density of CHISQ(29)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=31.89, lwd=2)
 abline(v=42.557, lwd=2, lty="dotted", col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies! Just added more context in an edit of my original question. @BruceET

Comment: Thanks. It seems you are doing a goodness-of-fit test to see if the normal distribution of  the `x`s is $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 1/2, \sigma=6).$ Beyond that it seems I guessed correctly about the use of $\mathsf{Chisq}(29).$ If you need further clarification about the procedure, it may be best for you to ask your instructor or a TA.

Comment: What is E(X)=ν in this context? What are E and v?  I understand X∼Chisq(ν=k) is the chisq distribution with k degrees of freedom and Var(X)=2k is variance of chi.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining. The letter $\nu$ (Greek 'nu') is (pretty much) standard notation for degrees of freedom. The mean of a chi-squared distribution happens to be equal to its degrees of freedom (see Wikipedia link) for the last sentence.

Comment: This was good. Thank you. So basically, 31.89 is 'normal' or expected for 29 degrees of freedom since it does not pass the critical value. This is why we fail to reject our null hypothesis; there is not a 'significant' statistical relationship based on this chi^2 distribution.

Comment: Substantially correct. To prevent confusion with a normal distribution, I'd avoid using the word _normal_ here. Perhaps say that an observed value of 31.89 is 'consistent with' observations from $\mathsf{Chisq}(29).$